# Open OSX application command line solution bypassing graphical admin password

Tags: macos, bash, applescript, automator

I have made an automator application which runs a couple scripts (and does not use any GUI, but it is opening a GUI for admin password because of my use of `with administrator privileges`). The main script is started using

`do shell script (quoted form of myCommand) with administrator privileges`

Because of this, when executing the application, a graphical admin password prompt is presented.

I am trying to execute this application automatically after install via bash and am wondering how I would be able to bypass the GUI password prompt; I'm looking for a way to execute the application via bash and run it silently (no GUI, no password prompt).

Because of the `with administrator privileges` all the common

`sudo open -a /Application/appname.app &`

`sudo osascript -e 'tell app id "com.app.bundleid"' -e activate -e end`

even running as root all still bring up the GUI password prompt.

Is there any way to open an application supplying the GUI password prompt via bash for OSX? Or is there a better way I should have executed the main script rather than `do shell script (quoted form of myCommand) with administrator privileges`?

Comment: I think "with administrator privileges" is popping up the password dialog. It cannot know, that the command will try to change the priviliges with sudo. Suggestion: Leave it out, put priviliges in /etc/sudoers and run your bash script with 'sudo' (This is the "quoted form of your command". Admittedly: I'm guessing. ATM I don't know nothing about applescript. :-)

Comment: It looks like this may be my solution: edit my way of using `do shell script` by supplying the password in-line and recompile the app like `do shell script "/path/to/script/file.sh" user name "adminusershortname" password "password" with administrator privileges` if my tests are successful, I will post it as an answer with some details to help future visitors. I'm still open to suggestions, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way in which I was able to bypass the GUI password prompt and still use `with administrator privileges` was to recompile the Automator app and supply the user and password in-line:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set myCommand to POSIX path of ((path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:script_name.sh")
    do shell script (quoted form of myCommand) user name "local-admin" password "local-adminpassword" with administrator privileges
    return input
end run
```

This accomplishes running the Applescript as with admin privileges, but without popping up the GUI password prompt. The app then runs silently, as I needed, and runs the script script_name.sh which in turn runs many other scripts and copies over other resource files out of (from myapp.app/Contents/Resources/) into system directories etcetera.

For the record, I needed it to act this way because I am deploying this app using Munki and wanted it to automatically run silently after install using a postinstall script:

```
#!/bin/bash
open -b "com.company.bundleidformyapp"
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If access for assistive devices has been enabled, you can use GUI scripting to interact with the password dialogs:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SecurityAgent"
    set value of text field 2 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window 1 to "pa55word"
    click button 2 of group 2 of window 1
end tell
```

```
osascript -e 'do shell script "ls ~root" with administrator privileges' &
sleep 1
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "SecurityAgent"
    set value of text field 2 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window 1 to "pa55word"
    click button 2 of group 2 of window 1
end tell'
```

Normally for example `sudo open -a Finder` doesn't open Finder as root, but `sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder` does.

Comment: +1 for the good tip as far as GUI scripting when assistive devices is enabled. Unfortunately, I don't think this could be my ultimate solution; I truly need it to run silently as I'm deploying this via Munki and it is quite possible the app may be installed/executed at the login window where no application GUI would be able to pop up.

Answer (score 1):

I see in your comment to your question that you will enter a password in your script. This is not a good idea. If you need to use a password in a script you can use the keychain to store the password and have the script retrieve it. This is a secure way to store your passwords because if you put the password in an applescript it is stored in clear text and thus can be easily retireved by anyone.

*Create the password item* - Open Keychain Access application and select the keychain in the left column. Then click File>New Password Item..., give it a name, account name (can be anything), and enter the password. You can "get info" on the item and change the Kind to "generic key" to differentiate it from other passwords if you want.

***NOTE***: You must put the name you have given the item into the passwordItemName variable in the code

When you run this code a dialog will pop up asking if you want to allow access to the item. If you click "always allow" then you will prevent this dialog from coming up again in the future. Or you can prevent this dialog altogether by getting info on the keychain item, going to the access control tab, and adding the "security" binary in the "always allow access..." section.

```
-- global variables are often saved in a writable applescript
-- so we ensure it's a local variable to prevent this
local pword

set pword to getPW()
do shell script "/path/to/script/file.sh" user name "adminusershortname" password pword with administrator privileges

on getPW()
    set passwordItemName to "ApplescriptAdminPass"
    do shell script "/usr/bin/security find-generic-password -wl " & quoted form of passwordItemName
end getPW
```

Comment: We are not too concerned about this, I do not like it though so I am open to other ways of working it out. I am compiling the Applescript as an Automator app ... I'm not sure if that can still be easily extracted as plain text? The problem with the solution you provided is I would need to do the keychain creation for 1000 computers (meaning I'd need to figure out a `security` command line method to accomplish the keychain stuff...time I don't have at the moment, but I will consider in the future). +1 for your insight and suggestion. Thanks

Comment: About seeing the plain text, I can use TextEdit to open an applescript file. You will easily see the plain text parts. I can do the same with an applescript application by finding the script file inside the application bundle and opening that in TextEdit. I haven't tried an automator file but it's probably the same.

Comment: It appears the Automator workflow is left in plain text even in compiled .app applications. Can be found appname.app/Contents/document.wflow ... I'll need to find a solution.

Comment: Yep, I suspected automator files were the same. Good luck.